# Cropping a map and preserving coordinate points in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, geospatial

I need to create a background map and then adding coordinate points using `ggplot2`. A simplified version of my code:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("png")
library("grid")

#creating background map
map <- map_data("world")
bg <- subset(map, region %in% c("France", "Italy","Switzerland"))
bg_map<-ggplot(bg, aes(long, lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon() #+coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-5,15), ylim=c(35,55))

xlim = ((ggplot_build(bg_map)$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$range$range))
ylim = ((ggplot_build(bg_map)$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range))
ggsave('map_backgroung.png', width = diff(xlim), height = diff(ylim),limitsize = FALSE, dpi=72)


#adding points
bg_map = readPNG('map_backgroung.png') 
capitals<-c("Rome","Paris","Bern")
Lat<-c(41.8947,48.8534,46.9481)
Long<-c(12.4811, 2.3488, 7.4474)
df<-data.frame(capitals,Lat,Long) 

MapCapitals= ggplot(df) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(bg_map, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                    -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) + # Background
  xlim(xlim[1],xlim[2]) + # x-axis Mapping
  ylim(ylim[1],ylim[2]) + # y-axis Mapping
  geom_point(aes(x=Long, y=Lat, color="red"), size=2)
```

[image: The position of the point is right.]

If I crop the background map using

```r
coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-5,15), ylim=c(35,55))
```

when creating the map with `ggplot`, the points no longer match correctly the map:

[image: error].

Different map projections (for example `coord_map`) don't work either. What is the right way to crop the background map without having issues?

EDIT: I don't generate background map and points at the same time because in the original code both bg map and points will use some `scale_fill` functions. I then want to turn the 2D map in a 3D map using `plot_gg` (the points becoming 3D objects). It seems to me that using the function `plot_gg` on something with multiple `scale_fill` objects, I have problems as `plot_gg` doesn't know which object should become 3dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because the objects you created are not spatial objects per se, so their relative locations appear to be treated independently in your method. If you zoom in on your second image, you'll see some very small long/lat axis tick, and that the proportions are distorted relative to your first image, e.g. it is 'squished' on the x-axis.

When plotting spatial data, it is *almost always* easier to convert them into spatial objects first. This is because `ggplot2` has the ability to interpret spatial objects using functions like `geom_sf()`, `geom_raster()`, and `coord_sf()`. So when plotting spatial objects, they will all have the same relative spatial location. Based on your data, I have set the CRS of all objects to EPSG:4326. Change this if necessary.

The resolution of bg in this example is relatively gross e.g. `resolution = 0.01` represents ~600m cell size at the southern extent of your data, but this can be increased for a nicer looking image. Or you could simply plot the countries as an sf polygon. The example image below is also low res so a higher dpi will improve the output. I also changed the `ylim` of p1 to allow a better side-by-side comparison.

```
library(sf) # For simple feature spatial objects
library(terra) # For raster objects
library(tidyterra) # For plotting terra objects in ggplot2
library(dplyr) # For data wrangling/pipes
library(ggplot2) 
library(patchwork) # Side by side plot

# Create sf of background map
bg <- map_data("world") %>%
  filter(region %in% c("France", "Italy","Switzerland")) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  group_by(region, group) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Get bg bbox for raster extent
st_bbox(bg)
#     xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
# -4.76250 36.68784 18.48584 51.09712 

#rasterize bg
bg <- rast(resolution = .01, 
           crs = "EPSG:4326", 
           xmin = -4.76250, 
           xmax = 18.48584, 
           ymin = 36.68784, 
           ymax = 51.09712) %>% 
  rasterize(bg, ., background = NA, "region")

# create point sf
capitals <- c("Rome","Paris","Bern")
Lat <- c(41.8947,48.8534,46.9481)
Long <- c(12.4811, 2.3488, 7.4474)

df <- data.frame(capitals, Lat, Long) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long","Lat")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)
 
# Plot 
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = bg,
              aes(x = x, y = y, fill = region),
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_sf(data = df, colour = "black", size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#D55E00", "#009E73", "#C74A8F"),
                    na.value = "transparent") +
  coord_sf(ylim=c(35,55))

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = bg,
              aes(x = x, y = y, fill = region),
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_sf(data = df, colour = "black", size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#D55E00", "#009E73", "#C74A8F"),
                    na.value = "transparent") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-5,15), ylim=c(35,55))

p1 + p2
```

[image: result]